# When is the inverse diagonally dominant?

Tags: matrix-analysis, matrix-inverse

There is a large literature devoted to studying the inverses of diagonally dominant matrices. I'd like to know if there is information about a so-to-say opposite situation: we have a matrix $A$ and want to find conditions under which $A^{-1}$ will be diagonally dominant.

One case which has been studied is that of strictly ultrametric matrices whose inverses are known to be Stieltjes matrices. But what if the original matrix has some negative entries?

UPDT: References to two papers, as requested some time ago:

(1) Li, Yaotang; Liu, Xin; Yang, Xiaoying; Li, Chaoqian
Some new lower bounds for the minimum eigenvalue of the Hadamard product of an M-matrix and its inverse. (English)
[J] Electron. J. Linear Algebra 22, 630-643, electronic only (2011).

(2) Ostrowski, A.M.
Note on bounds for determinants with dominant principal diagonal. (English)
[J] Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 3, 26-30 (1952).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide references from the "large literature devoted to studying the inverses of diagonally dominant matrices." Perhaps by looking at common features of these inverse matrices, it will be easier to ascertain the sort of conditions under which a matrix $A$ will have a diagonally dominant inverse.

Comment: After a long delay, I am adding two references...